# Defining tuple methods

Tags: methods, tuples, rust

Here's a `swap` function for two-element tuples:

```
fn swap<A, B>(obj: (A, B)) -> (B, A)
{
    let (a, b) = obj;

    (b, a)
}
```

Example use:

```
fn main() {
    let obj = (10i, 20i);

    println!("{}", swap(obj));
}
```

Is there a way to define `swap` as a method on two-element tuples? I.e. so that it may be called like:

```
(10i, 20i).swap()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is. Just define a new trait and implement it immediately, something like this:

```
trait Swap<U> {
    fn swap(self) -> U;
}

impl<A, B> Swap<(B, A)> for (A, B) {
    #[inline]
    fn swap(self) -> (B, A) {
        let (a, b) = self;
        (b, a)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let t = (1u, 2u);
    println!("{}", t.swap());
}
```

Note that in order to use this method you will have to import `Swap` trait into every module where you want to call the method.